# How do I split a circle shape into diaphragm-like segments in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

How can I make a vector image like this using illustator? (I'm interested in the shape of the triangles) *I'm moving from Photoshop to Illustrator and I have some difficulties...*
[image: Pic]

Comment: What have you tried? How would you do this in Photoshop? Why isn't that working in Illustrator for you? In general, you create the triangles then clip or cut them to the circle, you don't modify a circle from the onset.

Comment: Hi Giulio Cantadori, you will need to learn how to use the pathfinder options. [Illustrator Help / 
Combining objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html). For this specific effect, you can watch a video tutorial like this one: [Adobe Illustrator | Shutter Icon Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEOj-UnaiUs)

Comment: Please make an [edit] to your question with what you've tried.

Comment: This is a much better question than i originally anticipated... I think its good as is.

Answer (score 5):

Look at what you have. Circle divided in 6 pieces. divide circle into 6 pieces for starter. It is symmetrical by rotation. Draw one piece and copy. the triangle is pointing one side horizontally. This is what you get:

[image: outline]

**Image 1**: how i would do it

1. draw circle (mark center out with guides)
2. Draw line at 80 degrees
3. trim lines with shape builder
4. rotate back by 30 degrees
5. move point to verical with lower edge
6. rotate and repeat (ctrl+d)
7. color
8. make stroke wider white
9. outline

...

**Ammendum**:

If you want to be entirely accurate (my eyeball did this it very close but not perfect) note that the line has to satisfy following criteria:
[image: geometric solve]

**Image 2**: The geometric problem to solve.

PS: yes its the mirror image

Comment: Thats really interesting to see how you made that. I would have made basic triangles then used pathfinder to intersect or exclude the circle. Im not too familiar with Illustrator. Your way looks much more pro :)

Comment: @Lex there more then one way to do this for sure.. if id do this again id use offset as a live effect rather than the expansion of a stroke.... oh well.

Comment: @Lex your comment helped me appreciate the problem a bit more and realize i left something out of my sequence that might not be obvious.  So i added a section. TY... and now you all have to suffer my engineering mind :P Muhahaha

Answer (score 4):

I have read all valuable answers
my answer would be easier - I think

1. Draw the basic shapes and they are a circle and hexagone
2. Align them to the center

[image]

3. now break each anchor in the hexagon shape by selecting with the white arroe each anchor and click over `cut path at selected anchor points` select two by two because if select it all the cut path command will disappear as you select all the object not some anchors of it.

[image]

4. after that scale each line of the extracted hexagon separately in one way only.

[image]

5. give a stroke to those line and convert strokes into path. by selecting all lines and apply 10 point stroke then go the `objects>path>outline stroke`

[image]

6. when all lines converted to shape still selected go to pathfinder panel and select unite.
   [image]
7. sill the shape selected use sift to select the circle and go to the pathfinder panel and choose `Minus Front` and ungroup the result and delete the generated hexagon generated by our last operation. That's it.

[image][image]

Comment: Here is a conceptually easier way than both your sand mine http://i.stack.imgur.com/xdpou.gif